# reading file with condition

Tags: regex, file

How do i do this:

- read a file until some condition hits (like line contains /^ABC:/, for example)
- if condition hits, then continue to read until another condition hits (like newline). and write all these lines to some other file
- if condition doesn't hit, then do nothing.

Thanks,
-Brian

Answer (score 0):

**.NET**

1. Use [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) (and the [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx) method) to retrieve each line.
2. Use [String.StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) (Better than regex, less footprint, and does the same thing you're trying to accomplish, as far as I can tell)
3. Use [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx) (and the [WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt.aspx) method) to store your results.

**PHP**

1. Use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read the original and place each line in an array
2. Use [strncmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php) to see if the string begins with your "ABC:" match.
3. Use [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to place the match in to another file, noting the **FILE_APPEND** flag in the arguments list.

*Figured I would cover two popular languages, then update when the language is determined*

Answer (score 0):

**Bash**

```
infile="example.in"
outfile="example.out"
reStart="^ABC"
reEnd="^DEF"
found=0

cat $infile | while read line; do
    if [[ $found == 0 ]]; then
        if [[ "$line" =~ $reStart ]]; then
            found=1
            touch $outfile
        fi
    else
        if [[ "$line" =~ $reEnd ]]; then
            found=0
        else
            echo $line >> $outfile
        fi
    fi
done
```

The above will write the lines from $infile between the start ($reStart) and end ($reEnd) conditions, but not the lines with the start and end conditions themselves to $outfile. A little restructuring would take care of writing the start and end lines themselves if that's what you need.